# $\pi$ estimation with a coin

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a topic in which I have to estimate the value of $\pi$ by throwing coins and write the calculations in excel. I found this article but I can't figure out how $N_0$ was determined. Here in the example where $M=100$ and $N=1000$, $N_0$ is $80$ but why? And also in the second picture there is $M=100$, $N=1000000$, and $N_0= 78929$. Thank you !

[image]

[image]

Comment: $N_0$ is the result of a random experiment. In this experiment, one repeats the following trial N times. Each time you throw a coin $M$ times and evaluate whether the number of times you saw heads is exactly half ($M/2$). $N_0$ counts how often it happened that heads appeared $M/2$ times. The authors have conducted this experiment with $M=100$ and $N=1000$ and it (randomly) happened that N0=80.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment by @Andreas what authors have used are the results of their experiments so we can say they are experiment-based numbers which

I believe how can someone perform any random experiment for $N = 1000$ so they must have used the random program

[image: A python program where the value of N) is 81]

I did run the program a number of times and it was showing me close answers

But I guess we can also use $N_{\text{for tails}} = \text{Counting tails for }\frac M2$ times.

Counting for how many times head/tail appeared out of $M/2$ trails.

Comment: I'm  not trying to answer your question which I supposted by cannot but I just wanted to share the image as the result...

Comment: My recent run of the above code showed me exactly $N_0=80$ but for large values of $N, M$ it starts giving large errors but [not always when $N$ is very large and $M<100$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obPw8.png)